# Applying style to Table row with tr:hover css selector is not working in IE 8 (in case of *tr>td>div>input text* mouse hover action)

Tags: html, css

Mouse over the row(tr) is applying the tr:hover rule, but in case of mouse over the tr input child text content tr:hover rule is getting applied.

I am facing this issue only in IE-8. Can any one help me to identify the root cause.

[image: Can find the both cases]

Note: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3t2wry6m/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        tr{
            border-width: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: transparent;
            line-height: 23px;
            height: 23px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid #d3deed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            table-layout: fixed;
            position: relative;
            border-spacing: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }

        table thead tr {
            position: relative;
        }

        table th,
        table thead td,
        table tfoot td {
            border-width: .08em;
            padding: 2px;
            height: 16px;
        }

        table tbody td {
            border: 1px solid #d3deed;
            border-bottom-color: #d3deed;
            border-top-color: #d3deed;
        }

        table th {
            border: 1px solid #d3deed;
            border-top: 0;
            border-bottom: .24em solid #d3deed;
            border-bottom: .24em solid #d3deed;
            background-color: #e5edf5;
            color: #696969;
            font: bold 12px/1.5 'Lucida Grande', Tahoma, sans-serif;
        }

        table input{
          border-style: solid;
          background-color: transparent!important;
          border: 0;
          font: normal 12px/1.5 Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          width: 100%;
          cursor: text;
          height: 1.4em;
          left: 0;
          position: relative;
          top: 0;
          vertical-align: middle;
          border-radius: 0;
          -moz-border-radius: 0;
        }

        table tr:hover {
            background-color: green!important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
            <caption>Row hover</caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>header1</th>
                    <th>header2</th>
                    <th>header3</th>
                    <th>header4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                          <input readonly="true" type="text" name="" value="dsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfds">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                          <input readonly="true" type="text" name="" value="dsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfds">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                          <input readonly="true" type="text" name="" value="dsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfds">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                          <input readonly="true" type="text" name="" value="dsfsdfsdfsdfdsfsdfsdfsdfdsfds">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>    
</body>
```

Comment: `Note: Not shared the Jsfiddle, as it seems to be not working in IE-8.` ?? isn't this reason enough TO share the jsfiddle?

Comment: @odedta, I mean to say jsfiddle is not working IE-8. Any how I created the jsfiddle and given the reference in the problem description, please find it.

Comment: Then post it so we can try and help you make it work? hehe

Comment: Did you try to remove `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >`? did you try to add your testing website to the exclusion of IE's compatibility view website list?

Comment: @odedta, I have tried as you said, but no luck, here is the jsfiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/3t2wry6m/

Comment: Well, I used developer console of Internet Explorer 11 to move back to IE8 mode and it works as expected. :/ If you still have an error I suspect it has something to do with local settings like compatibility view.

Comment: @odedta, Yes, as u said it is working when IE11 is move back to IE8. But not in direct E8. Please try this in direct IE8.

Answer (score 0):

If you give up on traditional methods, use some jQuery:

```
$("tr").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','#0f0');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't use jQuery.

Comment: @odedta, Js solution can be costly, what abt using the z-index to overlap the input control with parent div. I am trying hard to overcome this issue.

Comment: Well... http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahover - `:hover` is supported in IE8 so there must be something else with your code that throws an error and by that causing `:hover` to fail. Link would be useful :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be I find some thing related to this. [IE 8 bug](http://marc.baffl.co.uk/bugs#ie7-ie8-hover-bug)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues you could look at, but the main problem seems to be the `DOCTYPE`.

The specified DOCTYPE targets HTML4 and refers to xhtml **strict** DTD; it means the document should be a valid xhtml one, and not closing the `input` tags is not permitted causing the browser to run in [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), causing the `:hover` to be broken.

If you can modify it, try changing the DOCTYPE by valid ones, such as:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Use the latter if you have to remain in HTML4 mode.

Also, the `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8" >` is not properly placed inside the `head` tag, which could also lead to rendering problems.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have tried what u pointed out but no luck. Please see [IE 8 bug](http://marc.baffl.co.uk/bugs#ie7-ie8-hover-bug) my finding